# How to sort datatables column with a combination of alpha numeric text and ignore alpha text

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I need assistance sorting the first column. I have a column with a mix of alpha numeric values. Is it possible for the column to ignore the alpha values and only sort by numeric values?

See test case: http://live.datatables.net/peyinuhi/2/edit

In my table, for example, AA-EC-1991-175 and AA-MW-1991-136 should ignore alpha values and sort by 1991-175 and 1991-136. As a result, the expected outcome should be if sorting ascending:

AA-MW-1991-136  (first)
AA-EC-1991-175  (second)
AA-EC-1991-190 (third)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example_full').DataTable( {

  responsive: true,
  paging: false,
  searching: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  bInfo: false,
  bSort: true,
 
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />

  </head>
  <body>


<table id="example_full" class="row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th data-orderable="false">2</th>
<th data-orderable="false" >3</th>
<th data-orderable="false" >4</th>
</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
  <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-EC-1991-175</p></td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-EC-1991-190</p></td>
<td>test2</td>
<td>test2</td>
  <td>test2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-EC-2011-50</p></td>
<td>test3</td>
<td>test3</td>
<td>test3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-EC-2014-90</p></td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>test4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-EC-2021-11</p></td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-MW-1991-136</p></td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-WE-2011-99</p></td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>OTS-AP-2010-03</p></td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-WE-2011-99</p></td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
   <tr>
     <td nowrap="nowrap"><p>AA-EC-2009-98</p></td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Comment: There are probably different ways to solve this - I recommend using DataTables support for [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data), which allows you to display your data as `AA-WE-2011-99` in the table, but to use a different value for sorting (e.g. `2011-99`). You can use their `render: function ( data, type, row ) { ... }` to convert `AA-WE-2011-99` to `2011-99`, and so on using JavaScript. That could be as simple as `data.substring(6)`, if your data's format is consistent for the entire column.

Comment: Stack Overflow has various ["orthogonal data"](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+orthogonal+site%3Astackoverflow.com) answers you can also look at for more examples.

Comment: Thankyou. I used orthogonal data and all worked out. Thanks again.

Comment: Good news! You are always welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow - especially if the answer could help future visitors to your question.